# How to train from scratch in TensorFlow object detection API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection

The github issue [2446](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2446) says if we want to **train from scratch**, we need to **comment** this line in the `model.config`:

```
#fine_tune_checkpoint: "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED/model.ckpt"
from_detection_checkpoint: true
```

I followed this issue and commented this line for training the SSD_mobilenet in my own dataset.
It can train and the **loss can reduce**, but the **accuracy keep at 0.0**.

I used the object detection api before with pre-train model from model zoo, it works well at mAP=90%, the only difference between these two tasks is the comment line in `model.config`.

I want to know **how to train a detection model from scratch using the object detection api in TensorFlow**. Thanks!

Comment: Did you get an answer to this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you to go on with fine-tuning your model instead of training it from scratch. Training a model from scratch requires more computation time for the model to converge, this means you are again starting with random weights and you are tuning them until they converge, this will converge eventually,  but the time to converge might be a week or a month as it is a large neural net.

In fine-tuning, you will use the previous weights, but you will tune them according to your own dataset, the end result is your model that helps you for the detection in your own dataset. The end model is also more or less a result of training from scratch, as the model will only work on your new dataset and new classes.

Comment: Thank you ! After i asked this question and keep on trained the model, the accuracy was growing although still lower than fine-tune the model at the same training steps.

Comment: ofcourse, it takes longer for the weights to get tuned, but  you will get good accuracy in one instance. if you are tired of continuous training, train it by checkpoints of your previous training, then it might be easy.
Thanks for accepting the answer.

Comment: Hello xinyuliu and saikishor, do both feature extractor layers' and predictor layers' weight get re-trained if commenting out "fine_tune_checkpoint"? What I want to do is keeping loading feature extractor layers' weight but starting with random weights on predictor layers' weight. Thank you.

Comment: @saikishor what about if one is trying to train on data that is very different from the pretrained models, such as radiology imagery?  Wouldn't it be better to train from scratch?

Comment: @olive_tree, no I wouldn't suggest that. Its always better to fine-tune the models. Training from scratch will consume lot of time and lot of resources, so I will strongly recommend you to start with fine-tuning. Moreover, the end accuracy and precision that you are gonna obtain in both ways will be more or less same. I hope it helps

Comment: @willSapgreen I am really sorry for the delay. Well if I am not wrong, as per your description it seems to me that you were referring to the Transfer Learning. Usually commenting the fine_tune_checkpoint will only make the process start from sratch

Comment: @saikishor thanks for the response!  You were right, scratch training too 6hrs+ and still no good accuracy.  Do you know of pretrained models in medical field for object detection? or ones on black and way xray imagery.. as i would think that'd be better than fine tuning from coco/openimages/etc.?

Comment: @olive_tree Glad you found about the complication in training from scratch. You are open to use models that were trained on COCO dataset, you should think deepnets are a net that extracts the features from the image rather than a pattern matcher. So, even if you use medical data for fine-tuning on a coco pretrained model, in theory it should work.

Comment: I agreed with transfer training. However, in my case, I need to strictly customize the model to recognize certain static objects. I would not use pre-built models due to the size of those files. I can't distribute it to production.